# Print Makefile variable as text

Tags: makefile, syntax, environment-variables

I didn't find anything about that, and i am trying to wrote this rule in my Makefile.

```
setenv:
    @echo "export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=."
    @echo "export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=$(NAME).so"
    @echo "export DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1"
    @echo "# Run eval $$(make setenv)"
```

So by running `eval $(make setenv)` in my terminal, the environment variable will be set.

But it's starting an infinite loop.

I've also try with:

```
\$(make setenv)
```

but nothing work ... What is the correct syntax for this ?

***EDIT:***

`\$$(make setenv)` Did the trick !

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why are the export commands echoed? `$$(...)` will expand to `$(...)`, which is shell substitution.

Comment: It's wrote on the last line, the command are echoed to use `eval` to started them. I found that cleaner than `$(shell export ...)`

Comment: If you're just using the Makefile to set environment vars for something else, a shell script would suit you better. If you need those vars for other recipes, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're setting environment variables for other recipes, note that:

- Using `$(shell export ...)` won't work: `$(shell ...)` always spawns a new shell, so anything that is exported into it won't be available outside of that particular invocation;
- Using `export` shell commands in a recipe will only work if `.ONESHELL` is used (not recommended), because each recipe line runs in a different shell.

The typical way to export environment variables to sub-makes and sub-shells is to use `export` as a Makefile directive, like this:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=$(NAME).so
export DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1
```

*Outside* any recipe.